# New Lightning component with custom 'Send to chat' button

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, liveagent, snap-ins

we have a basic lightning component that is generating a link, we would like to add a new button to send directly this content to the standard chat component, without agent interaction. Something like you can see in the following gif but not sure how they are doing....

[image]
How can I do It?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the following method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_sendMessage.htm

Comment: Please accept this answer to close the question.